# Return value in R function using for loop

Tags: r

I've made this simple code to test something that isn't working.

```
funcion=function(x,p){
 for(i in 1:p){
  return(x+i)
 }
}
funcion(5,5)
```

This returns the value 6, and not 6,7,8,9,10 which is what I would've expected and what I'm looking for.
Can someone explain why this works this way and how can I make it so that I get what I want?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to collect the output in an object and then return

```
f1 <- function(x, p) {
        # // create an object to store the output from each iteration
        out <- numeric(p)
        for(i in seq_len(p)) {
            out[i] <- x + i # // assign the output based on the index
         }
        return(out)
 }

f1(5, 5)
#[1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

---

In `R`, this can be executed without a `for` loop i.e.

```
5 + seq_len(5)
#[1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

---

The issue is that `return` inside a function returns only once.  So, it gets executed the first time with `x + 1` and it `return` that output instead of the full output

Comment: Thank you so much!
Specifying the length of vectors makes it faster to execute right?

Comment: @Python_begginer23 It will make it faster.  Most of the `R` functions are vectorized.  So, you don't need a `for` loop.

Comment: This is just an example. In the project that I'm actually doing I think I'd rather have a for loop.

Comment: @Python_begginer23 Good to know about the reasoning. Thank you

Comment: @Python_begginer23 in addition, you may also use `lapply/sapply` if you don't want to create output objects. i.e. `sapply(seq_len(5), `+`, 5)`